# UIAlertView and MVC

Tags: ios, uialertview

Is it bad design to display an alert view from outside of a view controller?

Let's say I'm trying to implement a secure web browser on iOS and I want to be able to handle bad certificates. For simplicity, my web browser consists of an HTTPS handler object and many view controllers. If I receive an invalid certificate, I want to pop up an alert view and ask the user whether or not the connection should proceed.

It seems to me that an alert view is presentation and belongs in the view controllers. But does it really make sense to create an alert view inside of every single task controller for a situation like this?

Would it make sense to create a single dedicated view controller solely for popping up these types of "global" alerts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience it is ok to call alerts from other objects for the most part, but do be aware that it may pose some difficulities if your view controller does not have control over those alerts.

For example I had a case where I needed my view needed to be aware if an alert was showing before trying to proceed.  But since some alerts were being called from other objects the VC was not always able to be aware of which alerts were showing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Per the HIG you might want to consider using an action sheet for this (see Alerts, Action Sheets, and Modal Views in the HIG) and http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html

and, to answer the 'does this make sense' question:  it does make sense to have UIAlertViews come from views, but depending on your app, you might want to use inheritance to manage the code organization for when/where the alertview is presented. YMMV.